# month of the date in Italian

Tags: 7

Use the module date-7.x-2.6, to insert a date dd / mm / yyyy in my content type. My problem is that when I view it, would that be translated into Italian for example "22 Settembre 1009" and now appears so: "22 Sep 1009". Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

On the "Manage Display" page for your content type (under admin/structure/types), you can adjust the format to use to display the date.

To adjust the formats, you can configure the date and time settings (admin/config/regional/date-time).

Comment: hello, under Administration> Configuration> Regional and language, I have the ability to bind 3 different formats 3 different types of data, but any format I choose the month is always written in English   ("September")   and not in Italian   ("Settembre").    That to me is a problem, but the default language is set to Italian.